# R or Python, text analysis and my particular situation

Tags: python, analysis, sentiment-analysis

I have recently undertaken a position which requires me to perform a lot of analysis, in particular on the text. My maths is average and I have only done basic programming in VB.

Especially, I am very interested in text and sentiment analysis. Would I be best suited to learn R or Python?

Comment: This question isn't the best format for StackOverflow as it is rather opinionated and quite vague. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't the [best format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for StackOverflow - it is rather opinionated and quite vague.

Personally I would tend towards R for most data analysis. Python is a fantastic general purpose language but for 90% of data analysis, I would choose R.

If you are a complete beginner, I would recommend the [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) book to get started with R, then I would recommend looking at the [tidytext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tidytext.html) package for text and sentiment analysis.

> Appreciate some advice as i dont want to start learning, realise its
>   not for me and start from point 0 again.

Just like learning French helps your Italian, starting with Python, realising it is not for you and then learning R would **not** be starting from point 0 again. Learning Python would be a valuable exercise that would help you become a better programmer. A good data analyst should be able to express themselves in multiple languages.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I do understand the question is not really stack overflow suitable but its been bugging me, I thought its best to get an answer from those who know the languages the best. 
My maths isnt fantastic, its not hopeless either, im just not great at summing things in my head quickly, i rely on a calculator alot. I dont know if this really has any relevance to anything.

Also you mentioned learning Python and then R would not make me start at point 0, would the same argument hold from learning R and switching to Python?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Agree this isn't the best format, but it's an honest question.
I think you'd have an easier time with Python than R if you don't feel confident with math. There are accessible tutorials on TryPython and DataCamp, and you may want to check out some of the free PDF eBooks on PacktPub. Also, there's a text for Python called "Automate the Boring Stuff", which is available chapter-by-chapter for free online, though it's more a cookbook and a lot of the material may go over your head the first read.

Comment: Hi MisterJT,  thank you for your response. I really wanted to know which is best for text analysis. Particularly presenting text and sentiment analysis findings to others. Can python do this. Whats very important is that the text analysis results can be presented in a way understandable to others..

Comment: sorry the above is a question, 'can python do this?' and is it a similar process to doing it in R? or alot more difficult? thanks all.

Comment: @user8424260, start with what generally you want the text analysis to look like. You will have to do some interpretation with any output you get, so find an analysis that will help you put it into a good form for a business consumer. 

Python's NLTK package should support whatever it is you'd like to do. You can also try some basic methods like Pandas value_counts or association rules in Orange to get a grasp on what your data looks like. 

For sentiment analysis, a good place for you to start would be with a tutorial on Twitter sentiment analysis in Python.